# Tereadata Error 3782 Improper column reference in the search condition of a joined table

Tags: sql, teradata

I made some changes (highlighted below) to some sql I inherited and I'm getting

> Error 3782 Improper column reference in the search condition of a
>   joined table

I'm not sure why I'm getting this message.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
with dqry_cc (mop_cd, mop_desc, group_branch_id, ecr_tmz_name, stn_stn_id ,  stn_id, grp_brn_id  ) as

(select   
    a.mop_cd ,
      a.mop_desc,
      so.group_branch_id ,
      t.ecr_tmz_name,
      so.stn_stn_id,
      s.stn_id ,
      s.grp_brn_id

   from      
   rfs.stn_ops_hierarchies so,
   rfs.mthd_of_pymts a,
   rfs.stns s,
   rfs.tmzs_map t

 where s.stn_id   =     so.stn_stn_id
    and a.mpt_mop_type_code = 'CC'
    and s.TMZ = t.TMZS_TMZ
    and so.group_id = '01'
    and so.region_cd = 'RGN_stl_99'
    and so.group_branch_id ='0101')

select *

from

(select   
  cc.group_branch_id as GpBr,
  cc.mop_desc as Descr,
  cast(SYSLIB.ERAC_GMT_TO_LCL(ph.pymt_dt, cc.ecr_tmz_name) AS timestamp(6)) as LocalPaydate,
  cast(SYSLIB.ERAC_GMT_TO_LCL(ph.pymt_dt, cc.ecr_tmz_name) as date)  as ph_pymt_dt,
  dr.dvr_srnm as DriverFName,
  dr.dvr_frst_name as DriverLName,
  ph.name as HolderName,
  pd.ticket_no as ECARS2,

cast( case when rb.ecr_lgcy_resv_nbr  is null then
         case when substr(pd.ticket_no,1,1) = 'D'  then
            'D'||substr(pd.ticket_no, 2,6)
                         else
                  null
                         end
       else   'D'||rb.ecr_lgcy_resv_nbr
     end  as CHAR(7)) as ECARS1,

  rb.rnt_agr_nbr as RntAgrNo,

case when ph.cr_card_trans_typ_cde='R' then
     -1*pd.pymt_amt
    else
       pd.pymt_amt
    end   as AMOUNT,

pd.cur_curr_cd as Curr,
  ph.CR_CARD_NBR as CardNo,

cast(ph.exp_dt as date format 'mm/yy') as ExpireDate,
  cast(0 as decimal(15,3)) as AUTH_AMT,
  cast(null as date format 'mm/dd/yyyy') as AuthDate,

ph.auth_nbr as AuthNo,

cast(null as char(2)) as Swipe,
  cast(null as varchar(60)) as PType,

 **pft.Settlement,
 pft.First_Six**

  from
  dqry_cc  cc, 
  rfs_rv.pre_applied_pymts_hdr ph,
  rfs_rv.pre_applied_pymts_det pd

left outer join
   (select      
    ra.rnt_agr_nbr,
    ra.ecr_ticket_no,
    ra.ecre_rent_cntrct_nbr,
    ra.ecr_lgcy_resv_nbr,
    cc.grp_brn_id --

 from           
   rfs_rv.rnt_agrs ra,
   dqry_cc  cc

   where   ra.sta_stn_id_orig_co = cc.stn_id QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  ra.rnt_agr_nbr ORDER BY ra.rnt_agr_nbr) = 1
   ) rb
      on pd.ticket_no = rb.ecr_ticket_no

 left outer join
       (select      
            dvr.dvr_srnm,
              dvr.dvr_frst_name,
              dvr.rdy_rnt_agr_nbr

       from rfs_rv.dvr_rras dvr

       where dvr.main_dvr_flg = 'MR'
       ) dr
       on rb.rnt_agr_nbr = dr.rdy_rnt_agr_nbr

 **left outer join
    (select
     ft.paymt_mdia_proc_sys_cde as Settlement,
     ft.prim_acct_frst_six_dgt_nbr as First_Six,
     ft.fin_tran_ref_id

      from paymt.fin_tran ft) pft
       on pft.fin_tran_ref_id =  cast(ph.paph_fin_trans_ref_id as decimal(19,0))**

   where ph.pymt_stn_id = cc.stn_stn_id
   and ph.mop_mop_cd = cc.mop_cd
      and ph.pymt_id = pd.pap_pymt_id
      and ph_pymt_dt  = 8/5/2015

) z
```

Comment: 1st: you should switch those old style inner joins to JOIN syntax, never mix old and new. 2nd: `ph_pymt_dt  = 8/5/2015` will never work, because `8/5/2015` is not a date, but an integer calculation resulting in `0`. Use a correct literal instead: `DATE '2015-08-05'`

Answer (score 4):

Your a mixing old and new style join syntax.  Your problem would never exist if you followed this simple rule:  *Never* use commas the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

The problem is the scoping of around the comma operator.  Although it is functionally equivalent to a `CROSS JOIN`, the first part is not a known alias for the second part.

If you fix `FROM` to remove all commas, your problem will be fixed, even if you only change the comma to a `CROSS JOIN`.  However, I recommend using the proper `JOIN`.

Comment: @dnoeth..........Thanks for the information.  I don't write sql on a regular basis so this is a continual learning process.